# How to convert XML to HTML using xslt

Tags: xml, html, xslt, xslt-1.0

Hi I want to convert my xml data to a HTML report. My sample xml looks somewhat like below.

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TestCases>
 <TestCase>
  <TCiD>TC001</TCiD>
  <Scenario>Verify the login functionality</Scenario>
  <TSResult>Pass</TSResult>
  <ScTime>50</ScTime>
  <Steps>
   <Step>Invoke application and enter a valid "Username"</Step>
   <Method>enter_Text</Method>
   <TestData>muralitharan_qac_mem</TestData>
   <StepResult>Pass</StepResult>
   <Time>08/05/15 14:34:27 </Time>
   <Filepath>SanpFilePath</Filepath>
  </Steps>
  <Steps>
   <Step>Enter the valid "Password"</Step>
   <Method>enter_Password</Method>
   <TestData>test!</TestData>
   <StepResult>Pass</StepResult>
   <Time>08/05/15 14:34:27 </Time>
   <Filepath></Filepath>
  </Steps>
  <Steps>
   <Step>Tap on the submit button</Step>
   <Method>click_On_Button</Method>
   <TestData></TestData>
   <StepResult>Pass</StepResult>
   <Time>08/05/15 14:34:27 </Time>
   <Filepath></Filepath>
  </Steps>    
  <Steps>
   <Step>Tool wait time</Step>
   <Method>ToolToWaitInMilliSeconds</Method>
   <TestData>10000</TestData>
   <StepResult>Pass</StepResult>
   <Time>08/05/15 14:34:27 </Time>
   <Filepath></Filepath>
  </Steps>    
 </TestCase>
 <TestCase>
  <TCiD>TC002</TCiD>
  <Scenario>Verify unsuccessful login for invalid Username</Scenario>
  <TSResult>Pass</TSResult>
  <ScTime>60</ScTime>
  <Steps>
   <Step>Invoke application and enter a invalid "Username"</Step>
   <Method>enter_Text</Method>
   <TestData>invalid_mem</TestData>
   <StepResult>Pass</StepResult>
   <Time>08/05/15 14:34:27 </Time>
   <Filepath>SanpFilePath</Filepath>
  </Steps>
  <Steps>
   <Step>Enter the valid "Password"</Step>
   <Method>enter_Password</Method>
   <TestData>test2!</TestData>
   <StepResult>Pass</StepResult>
   <Time>08/05/15 14:34:27 </Time>
   <Filepath></Filepath>
  </Steps>
  <Steps>
   <Step>Tap on the submit button</Step>
   <Method>click_On_Button</Method>
   <TestData></TestData>
   <StepResult>Pass</StepResult>
   <Time>08/05/15 14:34:27 </Time>
   <Filepath></Filepath>
  </Steps>     
 </TestCase>
</TestCases>
```

Now how I want my html report in a to be like:

```css
TestCase   Testcase Name                           Result    Time
TC001      Verify the login functionality          Pass      50
TC002      Verify unsuccessful login for           Pass      60
           invalid Username
```

On clicking TC001 the relevant steps for the testcase would show up as a table (something like a tree structure which can be expanded or collapsed).

Can anyone help me in how this can be achieved.

The xslt which I have created displays the Testcases in table, but I am not able to create a tree structure for the steps. The xslt is given below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:s="http://www.stylusstudio.com/xquery">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head /> 
            <body>
                <div style="text-align: none;color: #0000FF;">
                    <table align="none" style="border-style: outset;border-width: 2pt;width: 100%;background-repeat: repeat" cellspacing="1pt">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="border-style: inset;border-width: 2pt;padding: 2pt;vertical-align: middle;background-repeat: repeat">
                                    <div style="text-align: none;color: #0000FF;">
                                        <span style="font-weight: bold;text-decoration: underline;">
                                            <xsl:text>Test Case ID</xsl:text> 
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td style="border-style: inset;border-width: 2pt;padding: 2pt;vertical-align: middle;background-repeat: repeat">
                                    <div style="text-align: none;color: #0000FF;">
                                        <span style="font-weight: bold;text-decoration: underline;">
                                            <xsl:text>Test Case Name</xsl:text> 
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td style="border-style: inset;border-width: 2pt;padding: 2pt;vertical-align: middle;background-repeat: repeat">
                                    <div style="text-align: none;color: #0000FF;">
                                        <span style="font-weight: bold;text-decoration: underline;">
                                            <xsl:text>Result</xsl:text> 
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td style="border-style: inset;border-width: 2pt;padding: 2pt;vertical-align: middle;background-repeat: repeat">
                                    <div style="text-align: none;color: #0000FF;">
                                        <span style="font-weight: bold;text-decoration: underline;">
                                            <xsl:text>Execution Time (Seconds)</xsl:text> 
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <xsl:for-each select="/TestCases/TestCase">
                                <xsl:variable name="TestCase" select="." /> 
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="border-style: inset;border-width: 2pt;padding: 2pt;vertical-align: middle;background-repeat: repeat">
                                        <div style="text-align: none;color: #0000FF;">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="TCiD" /> 
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="border-style: inset;border-width: 2pt;padding: 2pt;vertical-align: middle;background-repeat: repeat">
                                        <div style="text-align: none;color: #0000FF;">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="Scenario" /> 
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="border-style: inset;border-width: 2pt;padding: 2pt;vertical-align: middle;background-repeat: repeat">
                                        <div style="text-align: none;color: #0000FF;">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="TSResult" /> 
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="border-style: inset;border-width: 2pt;padding: 2pt;vertical-align: middle;background-repeat: repeat">
                                        <div style="text-align: none;color: #0000FF;">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="ScTime" /> 
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Have you already tried out something? - add the XSLT code to your post.

Comment: It looks to me this is not an XSLT question, but a web design question (HTML + Javascript).  It looks like you want to know what HTML to use, that is, what would be the output of your transform (not what transform to use to achieve some output you already know about).  If you know what you want to generate, then post it, we'll be able to help you on the XSLT front.

Comment: @potame  I have added the xslt which I had created, but it only serves half of my job. Please help me out.

Comment: What do you use (or intend to use) to create the expendable structure? I think @FlorentGeorges is right, this question is more related to web design first.

Comment: @potame as asked by you I had added the XSLT which I had created. But I am not able to create the tree structure for the steps, can you help me in this

Answer (score 0):

i think this [site](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/xml/converting-xml-to-html-using-xsl.html) can help you very good.

Comment: Link-only answers are frowned upon. Can you explain why the site can help, quote some from it, write up a short summary of the solution, in case the site goes down.

Comment: @ADRI I have seen the site mentioned by you, but I still do not have the answer to create the tree structure for the steps.